# Start a Hangouts calls from a website

Tags: authentication, button, call, account, google-hangouts

I want to setup a "Hangouts"-button on my website in a way that my end-users have to click on a button, a sales person is being notified and will start a hangout call and shares the link of that call (via a chat, preferably). So end user can join that hangout call provided via the link without any google account and by just entering his/her name.

I have setup Hangouts on my site via https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button and my application via https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started but still I didn't find a programmatic way to do this. IMBK I think there is no document available either officially.